# Rotativa PDF export - unable to display inline and having a filename at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I found Rotativa as an easy way to export to PDF (works almost perfectly except CSS3 doesn't seem to be supported, maybe in a future version) ... but I wonder how to handle the `FileName` option.

When I

```
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("myViewName", "~/Views/Shared/_PDFLayout.cshtml", myModel)
{
    FileName = "myCorrectlyNamed.pdf",
    PageSize = ... // plus some more options
};
```

then I'll get `myCorrectlyNamed.pdf` for download. When I omit the `FileName` option, the PDF is displayed in the browser, but when I save it from there, it has just the default filename `document.pdf`.

How to generate and display the pdf in the browser and have a filename other than `document.pdf` when it's saved from there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `Content-Disposition` header to the `Response`. Using this header, you'll be able to tell the browser to **display the file inline** and also specify the **name that should be used** when user tries to Save the file.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { Inline = true, FileName = "myCorrectlyNamed.pdf" }.ToString());
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("myViewName", "~/Views/Shared/_PDFLayout.cshtml", myModel)
{
    PageSize = ... // plus some more options
};
```

Comment: Confirmed, this definitely worked for me. I was using RouteAsPdf, but the result is the same.  The key line is that Response.AppendHeader line.  I was previously specifying the file name in the call to RouteAsPdf, but after seeing this I removed that and placed it in the AppendHeader line and it worked perfectly.